# Background Image not shown

Tags: 6, media, theming

I use the [Bluemaster](http://drupal.org/project/bluemasters) theme for my site. Since I installed this theme, it worked well, but
a few days ago the background image was not shown.

I think this is because there are a [large photo in background](http://devel.drupaleasy.ir/amad-bsco).
How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I think this question should be closed.

Comment: I am sorry.My question is cheap!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css is the problem.   There is no images/bg.gif.  There is an image/bg.png file.

Change

```
body {
    background: url("images/bg.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #666666;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

to:

```
body {
    background: url("images/bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #666666;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```